# How to define resilience4j Fallback method when my actual methods has varargs

Tags: java, variadic-functions, resilience4j

We are using resilience4j Circuit Breaker, our monitored methods have varargs and return types are different so how can we define Fallback methods as I cant use last parameter as Exception as I have varargs as the last parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Resilience4j Circuit Breaker does not support varargs in a fallback - https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/issues/1294

Also, return type for fallback and original methods shall be the same. Though you can use List instead of varargs parameter to make fallback work.